# react https server not working but if i specify port number then it's working

Tags: reactjs, https, port

Please help me i am new in create-react-app.
i have a project noosmall.com. I have configure https for react but dev config file all pem, cert, key file in dev file. So strange when i type my domain for example https://www.noosmall.com it's does not work, but when i type https://www.noosmall.com:80 then it's shows me page that i expected. But if i disable https server then simple www.noosmall.com show the expected page.

Can anybody help me please, i do stuck in this.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to serve the website on a domain with the create-react-app bundled server. That's only for development ease. Here's [the official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) for how to deploy a create-react-app on static or dynamic servers with many examples. And if you're looking to serve over HTTPS that's on port 443, not 80.

Comment: I will be using Nginx to serve react app. But i was just testing and my another app is working which is https://www.mumato.com just for testing  purpose.  But with another it's not working. Since we do have option for serving static content by using various app such as apache or Nginx but Can't we still use npm run build and in server.js just serve the static content from there and yes https port is running on 433 and it's by react but simply it still serving if i specify :80 where i am running react app. Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Yes you should be able to use the server to serve the static files like you said. It seems like you're only serving on port 80 by default. If you're sure you're configure the ports and the cert keys correctly then it must be outside of your app.  If you're already using Nginx you need to configure it to also serve on 443. If not, it might be a firewall or something like that.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Can i ask you another this is when i deploy to live server after npm run build all static content is serve by the nginx. Will still in production but using app as development mode i ran npm run dev all react routes and their associates is serving by the nginx. After build do i still need to run npm start for the create react app.